# How can I efficiently replicate a pandas row, changing only one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    v1  v2
0   a   A1
1   b   A2,A3
2   c   B4
3   d   A5, B6, B7
```

I want to modify this dataframe such that any row which has more than one value in the `v2` column gets replicated for each value in `v2`. For example for the above dataframe, the result is as follows:

```
    v1  v2
0   a   A1
1   b   A2
2   b   A3
3   c   B4
4   d   A5
5   d   B6
6   d   B7
```

I was able to do this with the following code:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(row["v2"].split(','))>1:
        row_base = row
        for r in row["v2"].split(','):
            row_base["v2"] = r
            new_df = new_df.append(row_base, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        new_df = new_df.append(row)
```

however it is **extremely inefficient** on a large dataframe and I am would like to learn how to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas solution for 0.25+ version with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.assign(v2 = df.v2.str.split(',')).explode('v2').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  v1  v2
0  a  A1
1  b  A2
2  b  A3
3  c  B4
4  d  A5
5  d  B6
6  d  B7
```

For oldier versions and also perfromace should be better with numpy:

```
from itertools import chain

s = df.v2.str.split(',')
lens = s.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'v1' : df['v1'].values.repeat(lens),
    'v2' : list(chain.from_iterable(s.values.tolist()))
})
print (df)
  v1  v2
0  a  A1
1  b  A2
2  b  A3
3  c  B4
4  d  A5
5  d  B6
6  d  B7
```